# C++ re-call function if a try-catch falls?

Tags: c++, try-catch

A fairly simple question I believe but im a bit lost on how to re-call a function if a catch exception falls?

I have a main like so

```
while (state == true) //If there are exceptions thrown, you should report the problem and fairly seamlessly re-ask for a number
    {
        try
        {
            std::vector<int> numVec; 
            int i = getInteger();
            numVec.push_back(i);
            std::cout << i;
        }

        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            std::cout << "Something went wrong. How sad ..." << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Problem in : " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
```

The comment is the current question im answering.
I did attempt a while loop (well more like a draft/what i think has to happen (also note I can't change the *getInteger()* function so im not including it))

So what i require is if that first *try-catch* falls and an *exception* is found then the *try* is re-called until a valid input is found.

Comment: Just put `break;` where you want to break out of the loop.

Comment: I don't understand your question, while `state` is `true` the `try` is recalled regardless, and you don't seem to change it anywhere.

Comment: Don't use exceptions for normal operations, e.g. when the user enters a wrong number. Instead use some simple checks. Only use exceptions when something really bad happens (and you need some way to recover from it).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If the number read is successful, set the variable `state` to false and break out of the `while` loop. otherwise, print the desirable exception and ask to reenter the number.

```
std::vector<int> numVec; 
while (state == true) {
    try {
        std::cout << "Please enter a number..." << std::endl;
        int i = getInteger();
        numVec.push_back(i);
        std::cout << i;
        state = false; // set status to false as read is successful 
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Something went wrong. How sad ..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Problem in : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```